# Regex - Test extension if pass then test file name

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible in `regex` to check file name if it pass the extension test,
i have a `regex` that matches `.local` OR `.txt` for the file like `something.local` OR `something.txt`. Is there anyway to strict one file name in the test ?

Right now i am using `/\.(?:local|txt)$/` but don't know how to implement  that condition.
for example file name is *test.raw.local* so i want to check if it has raw.local then ignore that file .
I try `/\.(?:local|txt|!raw.local)$/` but didn't work!!

`valid:`

*-> test.local, hello.txt, script.something.local*

`invalid:`

*-> test.raw.local*

Comment: Huh? I don't understand your explanation. Please [edit] your question to show some examples of valid input and invalid input.

Comment: hi i updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookaheads in addition to your assertion for strings you want:

```
(?!.*\.raw\.local$)^.+\.(?:local|txt)$
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/18KiAd/1)